# A geometric limit

Tags: calculus, geometry

This is an exercise on limits I hope you like (I have loved it much when student).

In the figure below, the acute angle $\angle POQ=\phi$  is divided into $n$ equal parts and the  $OA_0$ segment  in $OP$ line has length equal to 1 . From the point $A_0$ successively draw acute angles all of them equal to $\alpha$ as shown below where each $A_k A_{k+1}$ segment makes an angle $\angle O_kA_kA_{k+1} =\alpha$ inside the angular sector $\angle O_kO O_{k+1}=\frac{\phi}{n}$ determining this iterative way a final segment $OA_n$ in line $OQ$ whose length is well defined.

Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}OA_n$.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a question to which you already know the answer. As such (and as intriguing as the question may be), it isn't really appropriate here. There are plenty of other websites available for posting mathematical challenges. You could perhaps make your question relevant to *this* site by providing your solution and asking for alternatives/improvements/etc.

Comment: Yes, I know the answer and it is not difficult to get with elementary considerations. I proposed it hoping that would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_k$ be the length of $OA_k$. Then by the law of sines,
$$ \frac{\sin(\alpha-\frac{\phi}{n})}{x_k} = \frac{\sin(\pi-\alpha)}{x_{k+1}} = \frac{\sin\alpha}{x_{k+1}}$$
Then
$$OA_n = \left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\left(\alpha-\frac{\phi}{n}\right)}\right)^n$$
This limit is an indeterminate $1^\infty$ form, so we will find the limit of its logarithm:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log OA_n = \frac{-\frac{\phi}{n^2}\cot\left(\alpha-\frac{\phi}{n}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} = \phi \cot \alpha $$
So the limit is $e^{\phi \cot \alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, more laborious but I think it more useful to undergraduate students is as follows:

Transform $OA_n = \left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\left(\alpha-\frac{\phi}{n}\right)}\right)^n$ as

[image]

So we have a definition of $e$ of the form $\lim (1+h(x))^{\frac {1}{h(x)}}$ when $h(x)\to0$ and thus we can calculate the limit of

[image]

which is equal to $\phi\cot\alpha$ getting at the end the solution $e^{ϕ cot⁡\alpha}$